# How to avoid a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

```
 if (alMethSign[z].ToString().Contains(aClass.Namespace))
```

Here, I load an exe or dll and check its namespace. In some dlls, there is no namespace, so `aclass.namespace` is not present and it's throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

I have to just avoid it and it should continue with rest of the code. If I use try-catch, it executes the catch part; I want it to continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `aClass` a `Type` instance? If so - just check it for null:

```
if (aClass != null && alMethSign[z].ToString().Contains(aClass.Namespace))
```

Answer (score 13):

Don't catch the exception. Instead, defend against it:

```
string nmspace = aClass.Namespace;

if (nmspace != null && alMethSign[z].ToString().Contains(nmspace))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the test for null in the if statement.

```
if(aClass.NameSpace != null && alMethSign[z].ToString().Contains(aClass.Namespace))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use an extension method to that checks for any nulls and either returns an empty string or the string value of the object:

```
public static string ToSafeString(this object o)
{
return o == null ? string.Empty : o.ToString();

}
```