# NullReferenceException unhandled fix?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a form with textboxes to input integers to form a time and the ideal working program basically means that the user has to select a runner from the listbox before they can type in any integers and click the `Process` button, but when I don't select a runner and click `Process` the `NullReferenceException` error is thrown for this line:

`lblRunnerInfo.Text = lstRunners.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r\n" + "Finished?: " + "\r\n" + "Time: " + txtHours.Text + ":" + txtMinutes.Text + ":" + txtSeconds.Text;`

The full code for the button is as follows:

```
private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Converts variables attached to textboxes to integers
   hoursInt = Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text);
   minutesInt = Convert.ToInt32(txtMinutes.Text);
   secondsInt = Convert.ToInt32(txtSeconds.Text);

   // Check if a runner has been selected
   if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
   {
      // Obtain selected runner
      Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;

      // Call the method in Gate class to process the runner
      gate.ProcessRunner(selectedRunner);
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please select a runner!");
   }

   // Converts the total to a string and outputs it as a label
   lblFinished.Text = gate.Total.ToString();

   lblRunnerInfo.Text = lstRunners.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r\n" + "Finished?: " + "\r\n" + "Time: " + txtHours.Text + ":" + txtMinutes.Text + ":" + txtSeconds.Text;
}
```

There may be something really simple I am missing, but I've never had a `NullReferenceException` before, so any help would be great.

Comment: "I've never had a `NullReferenceException` before, so any help would be great." First project? Debugging those is something that every .NET developer probably runs into way more often than they'd like. Just put a breakpoint on that line and see what's null. I'm guessing it's `lstRunners.SelectedItem`. Then do something to fix it: what should happen when someone clicks Process without selecting a runner? Should they even be allowed to do that, or should you have disabled the button?

Comment: Yeah I want the button to be disabled until the user selects a runner.

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/2530848). that will help you.

Comment: You should attach to `lstRunners`'s [`SelectedValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx) event to enable and disable your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the culprit is that `lstRunners.SelectedItem` is coming back as `null`. Try adding a conditional check for `null`, like this:

```
if (lstRunners.SelectedItem != null)
{
   // Converts the total to a string and outputs it as a label
   lblFinished.Text = gate.Total.ToString();
   lblRunnerInfo.Text = lstRunners.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r\n" + "Finished?: " 
                                                           + "\r\n" + "Time: " 
                                                           + txtHours.Text + ":" 
                                                           + txtMinutes.Text + ":" 
                                                           + txtSeconds.Text;
}
```

More about NRE's [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943465/avoiding-null-reference-exceptions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733383/how-to-avoid-a-nullreferenceexception).

Answer (score 3):

replace this statement

```
if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
```

with this:

```
if (lstRunners.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
```

Comment: if(lstRunners.SelectedItems.Any())

Answer (score 2):

A `NullReferenceException` occurs when you try to access an object that is null.  For example,  calling `myString.ToString()` when `myString` is null causes an ex.

In your code:

```
lblRunnerInfo.Text = lstRunners.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r\n" + "Finished?: " + "\r\n" + "Time: " + txtHours.Text + ":" + txtMinutes.Text + ":" + txtSeconds.Text;
```

These items appear to be controls added by the designer.  Calling the `Text` property on such controls is perfectly fine because they are initialized by the designer code.  The problem is with [Selector.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  From MSDN we know this property can return null:

```
Gets or sets the first item in the current selection or returns null if the selection is empty.
```

So you need to perform a null check:

```
        string selectedItemText = "";
        string newline = Environment.NewLine;
        if(lstRunners.SelectedItem != null)
        {
           selectedItemText = lstRunners.SelectedItem.ToString() 
        }            
        string result = String.Format("{0}{1}Finished?: {1} Time: {3}:{4}:{5}",selectedItemText, newline,txtHours.Text,txtMinutes.Text,txtSeconds.Text);
        lblRunnerInfo.Text = result;
```